# Connecting Strapi to NextJS/Apollo Client GraphQL -- Variable "$input" of required type 'XXX' was not provided

Tags: graphql, tinymce, react-apollo, apollo-client, strapi

Forgive me, this is very basic, but I haven't worked with GraphQL in a year or so and I'm missing the obvious.  I'm trying to connect a Strapi backend to a NextJS/Apollo Client front-end using GraphQL and the basic syntax is eluding me.  (This is a 'proof of concept' for a project we're working on, just to see if we can use Strapi, NextJS, and a rich text editor for our use-case)

Strapi has provided me with the `createPost` endpoint

[image]

To which, as far as I can tell, I need to send an object with a field `data` which contains my text.  I'm using TinyMCE's editor to edit the text and using apollo hooks to get the mutation

```
const TheEditor = () => {
    const [addPost, {data}] = useMutation(ADD_POST);
    const [theText, setText] = useState('')

    const handleEditorChange = (content, editor) => {
        console.log('Content was updated:', content);
        setText(content)
    }

    return <>
        <Editor apiKey='4564654765476547654'
                initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
                init={{
                    height: 500,
                    menubar: false,
                    plugins: [
                        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                        'insertdatetimse media table paste code help wordcount'
                    ],
                    toolbar:
                        'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
                        alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
                        bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
                }}
                onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
        />
        <button onClick={async e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            await addPost({variables: {data:theText}});
        }}>ENTER
        </button>

    </>
}

export default withApollo(TheEditor);
```

My mutation is

```
const ADD_POST = gql`
      mutation ADD_POST($input: createPostInput!) {
        createPost(input: $input) {
          post {
          text 
          }
        }
      }
`;
```

But I get the error

[image]

Clearly the issue is I need to go back and learn the basics of GraphQL syntax again.  In the meantime I'm hoping someone can point out the (egregious) errors of my ways.  I have been following along with the Apollo tutorial [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/), but I can't seem to make the leap from their code to mine.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `variables` should contain `input` property for this mutation, not `data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you variable name is input not data

```
<button onClick={async e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                await addPost({variables: { input:theText }});
            }}>ENTER
</button>
```